# Prompt. Как сделать проверку, чтобы строки и нечисловые значения не записывались в массив JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, prompt

Следующие задачи.

Необходимо внести в код дополнительную проверку, чтобы пустые строки (`''`) и нечисловые значения (`NaN`) не записывались в массив через prompt.

Интересует проверка в текущем контексте, без использования функций.

Буду благодарен за помощь и совет в решении.
Код ниже, а также в ссылке на codepen.https://codepen.io/monsara/pen/ERXMpq?editors=0012

```
'use strict';

let userInput;
const numbers = [];
let total = 0;

do {
  userInput = prompt('Введите число', '');

  if (userInput === '' || isNaN(userInput)) {
    alert('Было введено не число, попробуйте еще раз');
  }

  numbers.push(Number(userInput));

} while (userInput !== null);

for (const value of numbers) {
  total = total + value;
}

alert(`Общая сумма чисел равна ${total}`);
console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let userInput;
const numbers = [];

while (userInput = prompt('Введите число', '')) {
  if (userInput === '' || isNaN(userInput)) {
    alert('Было введено не число, попробуйте еще раз');
    continue;
  }
  numbers.push(+userInput);
}

alert(`Общая сумма чисел равна ${numbers.reduce((cur, next) => cur + next, 0)}`);
console.log(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, проверку на принадлежность введенного значения к числам лучше представить как `!isNaN(parseFloat(userInput)) && isFinite(userInput)`